# php light box galary management

Tags: php, image

I am a php programmer ,I have uploaded images in local host, as well as the names of the image files in database table.I was able fetch those path names from the table and render the corresponding images on the page in a column format.OS is linux.I want to bring the "Light box effect" to the display.Can you suggest me the technique or code or hyperlink to achieve my objective.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "light box effect" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Google lightbox -> click first result -> success

Answer (score 0):

For a lightbox effect I would recommend [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and it's simple enough to use...

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="shadowbox">My Image</a>
```

The `href` part would be generated from your database.