# PHP mysql query not giving extra output

Tags: php, mysql

I am a php programmer.When a page gets loaded some records are shown from a table(in a tabular format on the php page)  , on the page there are html **submit** buttons corresponding to whose **post** some other values are to be shown.

The problem is, the other values are shown along with the values which are shown when the page first loads. I want to show fresh set of values , without the default values which are shown when the page first loads.

It has to be mentioned that the default page load values which are fetched from the table is **not done** corresponding to  any isset($_POST) unlike the other fresh values.

can you help me out?

Comment: Dude, you don't have to [tell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668642/php-light-box-galary-management) [us](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688389/state-of-art-rating-system-in-php) **[every](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691458/dynamic-radio-button-creation-along-with-their-labels) [single](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712620/retaining-values-of-radio-buttons) [time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766941/dynamically-adding-textboxes-to-a-form-by-the-click-of-a-button)** that you're a PHP programmer. **We know.**

Comment: @BoltClock Impressive linking capabilities. But why go through this hassle?

Comment: What does the question have to do with mysql?

Comment: @BoltClock But that's how they taught us at the PPA meetings!

Comment: @Pushan Could you show some code? (and also, accept some answers to your other questions)

Comment: @Spiny Norman: The what now? :O

Comment: @BoltClock You know, the mutual aid group for recovering PHP programmers.

Comment: @BoltClock: I still don't believe him.

Comment: @symcbean: Actually... neither do I.

Comment: Ok, to get back on track... Could you prehaps post some code to make it easier to spot your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using some random numbers in the query or other patterns in the query so that you get records afresh than getting the same records every time you visit the page.

Hope my understanding is right.